# Verbose parent/child matcher errors for Rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

Given the following code, when I get a failure, I would like to see both the parent and child diff's shown. Currently, if I have a mismatch at the children level, I only get feedback that my parent did not contain the expected children, not what my actual children were.:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_categories do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    expected.each do |ex|
      lines = ex.map do |ex_line|
        an_instance_of(Model::SubCategory).and(have_attributes(ex_line))
      end
      expect(actual.categories).to include(an_instance_of(Model::Category).and(
                                             have_attributes(sub_categories: contain_exactly(*lines))))
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you add an excerpt from your spec how you use it? It would help a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you need to implement [`failure_message`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-2/docs/custom-matchers/define-matcher#overriding-the-failure-message) method in order to format expected error message, and here you can create a string of diff you would like to see:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_categories do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    expected.each do |ex|
      lines = ex.map do |ex_line|
        an_instance_of(Model::SubCategory).and(have_attributes(ex_line))
      end
      expect(actual.categories).to include(an_instance_of(Model::Category).and(
                                         have_attributes(sub_categories: contain_exactly(*lines))))
    end

    failure_message do |actual|
      # here you are able to use both `actual` and `expected`
      # to create your error message
    end
  end
end
```

Please , provide more information about your domain, so I can try to help you with preparing proper error message.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Excellent, thanks! That will be enough to produce the desired results. Bounty can be released in 7 hrs or will automatically be awarded to you later if I'm not online

Comment: Hey! Glad to help! Looking forward to release! Best! :)

Comment: Thanks again. Implemented after adding some adjustments, such as catching failures in `match` block, to allow pretty printing objects before passing back to `failure_message`, which only allows strings, AFAIK.